# Visual Studio 2012: can't add Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

In my project I have a report.rdlc which I would like to use in my Windows Forms class. However, when I try to add a Report Viewer component my visual Form this error pops up:

[image: Error]

Comment: Couldn't you find a bigger picture? We can barely see it.

Comment: I am very new in VS2012, what should i do to resolve it?

Comment: Referene here > http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/38323050-749f-4616-b513-b6a410e56d78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution helped me to solve my problem

1. I downloaded and installed Report Viewer 2010 version.
2. Then I added Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL assembly file from
3. `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`.
   And finally I added the following line to the .ascx file. `<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>`